# Could not install package ServiceStack.Interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, servicestack

I'm trying to install ServiceStack nuget package- but no luck.

Environment:
 - Visual Studio 2012
 - .Net 4.5
 - Project type- Empty webSite

**Command: Install-Package ServiceStack**
It  starting  package installation process but at the end of the end everything  roll back and show error message:

**Install-Package : Could not install package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.38'.** You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.3', but
 the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  ServiceStack
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I've tried old version of ServiceStack- but result always the same.
Whould you please clarify- how to fix  described issue?

Comment: Interesting. ServiceStack.Interfaces is a pure PCL library which should support every .NET platform (except for XBox). Do you have the latest version of NuGet installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and while searching for a solution came to this thread. Based on @mythz's comments of checking the NuGet version I was able to resolve the issue.

You need to go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates tab. Find Nuget Package Manager and click the Update button. Once NuGet is updated, you should be able to install ServiceStack.Interfaces without any issues.